Cypher logic gates -> where all
I'm looking for help with the syntax to create logic gates.

I want to identify in which sims, which gates are open.

gate a:

only requires event 1
open in sim 1,2,3


gate b:

requires event 1 & 2
open in sim 2 & 3


gate c:

requires event 1, 2,3
only open in sim 3



Data created using:
CREATE 
(a:Gate {name: 'gate a'}),
(b:Gate {name: 'gate b'}),
(c:Gate {name: 'gate c'}),
(x1:X {name: 'sim 1'}),(x2:X {name: 'sim 2'}), (x3:X {name: 'sim 3'}),
(e1:E {name: 'event 1'}),(e2:E {name: 'event 2'}), (e3:E {name: 'event 3'}),
(e1)-[:AND]->(a),
(e1)-[:AND]->(b),
(e2)-[:AND]->(b),
(e1)-[:AND]->(c),
(e2)-[:AND]->(c),
(e3)-[:AND]->(c),
(x1)-[:HAS]->(e1),
(x2)-[:HAS]->(e1),
(x2)-[:HAS]->(e2),
(x3)-[:HAS]->(e2),
(x3)-[:HAS]->(e1),
(x3)-[:HAS]->(e3)


Assuming that your DB has no duplicate HAS or AND relationships (between the same pair of nodes), you can:

Count the number of Events for each Gate.
Create a mapping from the internal ID of each Gate to its count.
Count the number of Events for each sim/Gate pair.
Keep only sim/Gate pairs that have an Event count equal to the count in the map for the same Gate.
Return the remaining pairs.

For example (this also sorts the results by sim.name):
MATCH (e)-[:AND]->(g:Gate)
WITH ELEMENTID(g) as gId, COUNT(e) AS gEventCount
WITH apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([gId, gEventCount])) AS gIdCountMap
MATCH (sim:X)-[:HAS]->(event)-[:AND]->(gate)
WITH sim, gate, gIdCountMap, COUNT(event) AS sgEventCount
WHERE gIdCountMap[ELEMENTID(gate)] = sgEventCount
RETURN sim, gate
ORDER BY sim.name

The result of above query is:
╒════════════════════╤════════════════════════╕
│sim                 │gate                    │
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│(:X {name: "sim 1"})│(:Gate {name: "gate a"})│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│(:X {name: "sim 2"})│(:Gate {name: "gate a"})│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│(:X {name: "sim 2"})│(:Gate {name: "gate b"})│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│(:X {name: "sim 3"})│(:Gate {name: "gate a"})│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│(:X {name: "sim 3"})│(:Gate {name: "gate b"})│
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│(:X {name: "sim 3"})│(:Gate {name: "gate c"})│
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘


Awesome thank you. This is a crash cource in Cypher-CTE's and apoc for me :heart:
